# javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010016: Not a multi part request

Tags: jsf, primefaces

We're working on an application with Jsf/Primefaces and Java2EE.

We have a problem with this stack:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010016: Not a multi part request

According to my research, it seems like when you submit a form with an attachment, you must have some encoding configuration (something like multipart/form-data).

We already have this configuration but the error still persist.

Here is our only form used to send an attachment:

[image: img]

Do you have any idea to resolve this issue?

Rgds,

Comment: Hi, please read [ask] and [mcve] and the 'learn more' page of the [tag:jsf] tag.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. The problem is that we don't have a reproducible example. It occurs on our application in production, that's why we don't know what the user did therefore we can't reproduce this. The only thing we have is this log, and we are looking for any clues that can help us to understand this problem.
On our application user have to upload a file, and then he also has to download one. We think that the problem is linked with this and the configuration we gave above.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Ok, but you do know if it **always** happens or not... Maybe users just press a cancel button...